# How can same code running with same libraries produce different results when executed in raspberry pi and anaconda3 in windows?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3, scikit-image

i have run same code in syder which produce a result. i ran the same code in raspberry pi and the result is different. I have tried everything possible but it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point computation is [not exact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), so it is expected that results will be different between different processors, versions of libraries, etc. Since the processor in the Raspberri Pi is completely different from that in most laptops (ARM vs Intel), I would not expect exact matches between the results on both.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer sir.

How to fix the Floating Point computation in Raspberry pi to obtain the same result as in laptops?